# Change coordinate system in a CSV file

Tags: r, coordinates, r-sf

I have a csv file. It has x and y columns for longitude and latitude. The coordinate system is WGS84. The following picture shows a part of my table.
[image: CSV file with lat and long columns]

I need to add two new columns to my csv file and change the coordinate system from WGS84 to NAD83/BC Albers and put the results in the two new columns.
Please tell me how I can do it in R?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you have R spatial packages installed on your system (`sf`, `rgeos`, `PROJ`)? [windows or linux/mac os]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight forward using the sf package:

```
#create some data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID=1:10, y=runif(10, 48, 50), x= runif(10, -122, -118))

#convert
library(sf)
newcoords <- sf_project(from = st_crs(4326), 
           to = st_crs(3005), df[, c("x", "y")]) |> as.data.frame()

        V1       V2
1  1356700 402722.2
2  1346440 425753.3
3  1492117 482291.2
4  1398129 548942.2
5  1524425 402642.4
6  1430914 549426.5
7  1493005 565419.1
8  1578512 510951.0
9  1401795 486993.0
10 1529783 371986.7

cbind(df[ ,c("ID", "x", "y")], newcoords)
```

Referenced: https://epsg.io to determine the proper CRS number.
Another possible CRS is 3153 (provides very similar results, apparently better accuracy).

Comment: A slight variant, as, for whatever reason, OP wants both 4326 and 3005 coords in same data.frame.